# partition functions and Galois representations?

Tags: partitions, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

The recent [answer's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52744/what-is-the-relationship-between-modular-forms-and-maass-forms/52753#52753) link to Ono's work makes me ask and wonder if his [new results](http://www.aimath.org/news/partition/folsom-kent-ono.pdf) on partition functions tell something about Galois representations? (Hoping that question is not a case of [this](http://m.discovermagazine.com/2010/sep/25-modern-humans-smart-why-brain-shrinking/article_view?b_start:int=0&-C=))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dear Thomas,

As far as I know, this work is not related directly to Galois representations, but is rather a particular calculation in the theory of $p$-adic modular forms (although it is not really described this way explicitly in the paper).
The $p$-adic theory of modular forms of half-integral weight was developed in the [2004 Ph.D. thesis](http://condor.depaul.edu/nramsey/math/papers/harvard_thesis/huthesis.pdf) and subsequent papers of [Nick Ramsey](http://condor.depaul.edu/nramsey).  (See Nick's comment below this answer, and the several papers available on his web-page.)  The deduction of the results of Folsom--Kent--Ono from Ramsey's thesis is explained in a [short note](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~fcale/Files/FKO.pdf) recently written by my colleague [Frank Calegari](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~fcale).

The key idea is that iterating the $U_{\ell^2}$ operator on a space of ($\ell$-adic) modular forms
of half-integral weight projects to the ordinary part of the space, which is finite-dimensional and more-or-less explicitly computable.  Applying this procedure to the modular form $1/\eta$ of weight $-1/2$ (recall that $1/\eta = q^{-1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)^{-1}$ is the generating
function for partitions) gives the results of Folsom--Kent--Ono.

[Added: The shift from $p$-adic to $\ell$-adic in the second paragraph is made just because in the work of Folsom--Kent--Ono, and so also in Calegari's note, the distinguished prime is called $\ell$.  On the other hand, when talking about this area in general, people normally speak of $p$-adic modular forms rather than $\ell$-adic ones.]

Comment: Actually, my thesis only treated forms of positive classical half-integral weights (those of the form $k/2$ where $k$ is odd and positive), though I doubt there is any real obstruction to using the arguments there with $k=-1$.  (Also, the published article "Geometric and $p$-adic modular forms of half-integral weight" is a better reference to the content of my thesis.)

However, the subsequent paper "The half-integral weight eigencurve" treats general "$p$-adic half-integral weight," which includes negative classical weights (and a lot more).


Comment: Dear Nick,  Thanks for the clarification; I'll make an edit to reflect this.