# How to interpret Maass forms of higher weight into the automorphic language?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm so sorry if this post is inappropriate for this site. I'm a new learner on automorphic forms and representations.

In the article *Automorphic forms and automorphic representations* by Borel and Jacquet in the Corvallis volume, they defined (in 1.3) an automorphic form on $G(\mathbb{R})$ as a smooth complex valued function $f$ on $G(\mathbb{R})$  satisfying

1. automorphy condition: $f(\gamma x)=f(x)$ for $\gamma \in \Gamma, x \in G(\mathbb{R})$
2. $f$ is $K$-finite on the right.
3. There exists an ideal $J$ of finite codimension of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ which annihilates $f$.
4. Growth condition.

(Here $G$ is a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra, with center of universal enveloping algebra $Z(\mathfrak{g})$. $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb{R})$, $\Gamma$ is an arithmetic subgroup of $G(\mathbb{Q})$.) The space is denoted by $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{A}(G, \Gamma, K, J)$.

Then in (1.4), they provide an example when $G=GL_2$, $\Gamma=GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $K=O(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $J=(\Delta - \lambda)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\Delta$ is the Casimir element (the Laplacian) and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I can see that this can be interpreted as a Maass form of weight 0 and level $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

**My question**: can Maass forms of higher weight $k >0 $ be interpreted in this way? And how?

In my understanding of (1.4), via Iwasawa decomposition, $\Delta$ can be realized as the usual Laplace-Beltrami operator on the upper half plane. But for Maass form of positive weight $k$, it is defined to be an eigenfunction of the **modified (weight k)** Laplacian
$$
\Delta_k := -y^2 \left( \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) + iky \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}.
$$
A Maass form of weight $k>0$ is required to be annihilated by $\Delta_k - \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. But **I'm confused on how to regard $\Delta_k$ as an element of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$** and got stuck here.

**Further question**: I have seen that the **weight $k$** holomorphic modular forms lies in $\mathcal{A}(GL_2^{+}, SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), SO_2(\mathbb{R}), \langle \Delta - \frac{k}{2}(1-\frac{k}{2}) \rangle )(\sigma_k)$, where $\sigma_k$ is the one-dimensional (irreducible) unitary representation of $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto e^{ik\theta}
$$
and by $(\sigma_k)$, I mean considering the $\sigma_k$-isotypic part of $\mathcal{A}$. And the space of **weight zero** Maass form can be identified with $\mathcal{A}(GL_2^{+}, SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), SO_2(\mathbb{R}), \langle \Delta - \lambda \rangle )(1_K)$, where $1_K$ is the trivial representation of $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$. Taking $\lambda := \frac{k}{2}(1-\frac{k}{2})$, we see that the space of **weight zero** Maass form is **orthogonal** to the space of holomorphic modular forms of **weight $k$** in $\mathcal{A}(GL_2^{+}, SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), SO_2(\mathbb{R}), \langle \Delta - \lambda \rangle )$. **Then how does weight $k>0$ Maass form come into play?** **Is this the correct understanding of the post [What is the relationship between modular forms and Maass forms?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52744), especially the answer by GH from MO?** And by saying **orthogonal**, what is the inner product? Or we need to restrict our discussion in $L^2$-space?

So sorry for such a long post on such a trivial question, especially for this site, and thank you all for commenting and answering.

Comment: I recommend that you read Section 4.12 in Goldfeld-Hundley's book "Automorphic Representations and L-Functions for the General Linear Group, Volume 1".

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you for your help! I have read the section you mentioned above (actually before posting this post) and seen how a Maass form of higher weight can be regarded as a function on $GL_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$ via the slash operator. Yet I’m still wondering how to interpret the **weight $k$** Laplacian as an element of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$, in order to **transfer the property of being an eigenfunction of $\Delta_k$ to the $GL_2^{+}(\mathbb{R})$-context**, and hence put it into the framework of Borel & Jacquet’s article. :)

Comment: The Casimir operator acts on the lifted adelic form in the same way as $\Delta_k$ acts on the original classical form. Note that the definition of the lift involves $k$, since the adelic form is left $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$-invariant even though the classical form is not left $\Gamma_0(N)$-invariant.